# Is it possible to use WiFi Hotspot to serve files?

Tags: networking, wireless, hot-spot

I want to be able to serve files from my laptop, over wifi, with no router or internet connection. My goal is to make it so that when I travel to the area without internet, my other devices(iPad) could wirelessly download files from my laptop.

Would this be possible to do using WiFi Hotspot(or in some other way)? Would it be difficult? Can you help me out?

[lspci output for my card](https://pastebin.com/3jMY4Q05)

[iw list output](https://pastebin.com/tGEqgbEi)

Answer (score 1):

I have a solution for you and it implies installing software only on your laptop.

1. install `hostapd` to create a wifi access point
2. install `dnsmasq` to handle DHCP and DNS
3. install a webserver, like `nginx`
4. compress the files (e.g. **.zip**) and store them on the nginx root folder
5. connect any wireless device to that wifi access point and insert its ip address into a browser

I didn't gave you a tutorial as there are tons of tutorials on Google.

I know that it's a tedious process, but now you download any file from your laptop.

And you can go a step further to create a virtual domain on nginx to something you can remember (e.g. **myfiles.com**). This way you don't have to connect via ip address.